# How to compare 2-number elements in an array with a 2-number list to generate a boolean-type array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, boolean

for example

```
a = np.array(([0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]))
c = np.array(a == [0, 1])
```

in this way I just get

```
`array([[ True, False],
        [ True, True],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True]])`
```

but I want to get 
`array([False, True, False, False])`
of course I can ravel c and use a `if(c[i]==1)&(c[i+1]==1)` to give "True",

```
c = c.ravel()
cshape = list(c.shape)
del cshape[-1]  
d = [] 
for i in range(0, len(c), 2):
    if (c[i]==1)&(c[i + 1]==1):
        d.append(True)
    else: 
        d.append(False)
d = np.array(d).reshape(cshape)
```

but for a large system, it could be a cost of resources.
is there any simple method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: a = np.array(([0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]))
In [2]: a==np.array([0,1])
Out[2]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True]])
```

Just check whether all elements of a row are `True`:

```
In [3]: _.all(axis=1)
Out[3]: array([False,  True, False, False])
```